# What's the difference of VS2008 and VS2010 when I do a Load Testing?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, load, load-testing

I have a project and I want to do some load testing to it.
I have a VS2008 test Edition now, but there is another choice: VS2010 Ultimate.

Should I do my load testing on VS2010 Ultimate?
Is it a better choice?
Why?
What's the difference of VS2008 and VS2010?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main difference is that the Visual Studio agent licencing has changed. 2008 has a per cpu licence and 2010 is licences per 1000 virtual users.

This means that 2010 is significantly more flexible than 2008 for load testing with multiple machines.

As you are licenced for the *Test Edition* of 2008, you may have to pay more (double?) to get a licence for 2010 *Ultimate*, other than that there is no reason to use VS2008.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff400219.aspx) is an article with specific mention to the new stuff.
I have not missed those items in 2008 (yet).

Comment: Many thanks! Besides licence issue, is there any other advantages of 2010 than 2008?For example, more flexible with more simulator of net.

Comment: Thanks again, it is useful to me!